# changing text first time works but after that i get a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in unity and I need to change a bit of UI text to display the player's money. the first time changing it in the start function works like normal, however when I try to change it from a different function (within the same class) it gives me the following error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here's the class where the code is running in:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class money : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static money instance = new money();

    private float Money = 100;
    public Text MoneyText;

    void Start()
    {
        setText();
    }

    public void setMoney (float mon)
    {
        Money += mon;
        setText();
    }

    public float getMoney ()
    {
        return Money;
    }

    public void setText ()
    {
        MoneyText.text = Money.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the code that calls setMoney that is resulting in the error:

```
money.instance.setMoney(-turretBuildCost);
```

I hope someone has encountered the same issue and can help me.

Comment: What's `MoneyText` - you never initialise it... is this your whole code? I can't see how this would ever work since `setText` references `MoneyText.text` but `MoneyText` is always null.

Comment: ```MoneyText``` is a UI text that is set inside the unity inspector.
This is not my entire code, just the class that I think is relevant for my problem.

Comment: What line in the stack trace is the exception thrown on?

Comment: Where is the error being thrown, and why are you using a singleton?

Comment: @Carl on line 31.

Comment: Thanks, but you will need to edit your question to show us which line of code is 31

Comment: @Carl ```MoneyText.text = Money.ToString();```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on it and see which of MoneyText or Money is null

Comment: Also, how many GameObjects do you have this script attached to? Is it just the one? If there's more than one, can you verify that you have MoneyText set for all of them.

Comment: @Carl MoneyText seems to be null. I don't know how though seeing as during the start function it wasn't null.

Comment: How are you calling this class? Are you just doing "money.SetMoney(5.00)"? You need to get the script from your gameobject, and then call the function from that gameobject component, otherwise it's going to behave how it is.

Comment: @GarrisonBecker I only have the script attached to 1 gameobject and MoneyText is set for it.

Comment: If you can provide the code that you're calling this class from it would help.

Comment: @GarrisonBecker this is how I call the class 
```money.instance.setMoney(-turretBuildCost);```

Comment: Okay, I'm almost certain that's why. "instance" is static, so it immediately news up an instance of your "money" class. Whereas you have this MonoBehaviour as a component on an object where you're trying to display the MoneyText. That script goes straight into Start(), and isn't interacting with your static instance whatsoever, so it never sets MoneyText for the static instance you're trying to use elsewhere. I'll write up an answer for 2 ways you can go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're trying to use the static instance you created to update your MoneyText, but this static instance never had the MoneyText property set, because the only place you're setting MoneyText is on the GameObject that you have the script attached to through the Unity Editor.

1st way, if you want to try to keep your singleton pattern, is to do the following:

```
public class money : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static money instance = new money();

    private float Money = 100;
    public Text MoneyText;

    void Start()
    {
        instance.MoneyText = MoneyText;
        setText();
    }

    ...
}
```

This will set the MoneyText property using the property from the object that you already have set up.

The 2nd way is if you want to avoid using a singleton pattern, where you instead have to get the component from the GameObject to get the instance to call SetMoney from.

Like so:

```
YourGameObject.GetComponent<money>().setMoney(5.00);
```

Comment: Thank you that did it